# Android/Microsoft Dynamics CRM App Development Project

Tags: android, dynamics-crm

I need some help with my project. The development consits on an Android App, which connects Microsoft Dynamics CRM web service, and collects data from previously created Contacts. Then, the user can see info, send email or call to the Contact selected.

My questions are:

Is it necessary to run a Microsoft Server for this link between Dynamics and App ? Somehow without having to use this? I just want to collect Contact data.

I'm using this app as a template / reference / tutorial :

https://github.com/DynamicsCRM/Android-Activity-Tracker-for-Dynamics-CRM

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What is Microsoft Server in this context?

Comment: The app would need to connect to *a* CRM server, you don't necessarily have to run it yourself.  So if you had an online trial org, you should be able to connect the app to it.

Comment: Microsoft Server 2012, for example.

Comment: I have a trial https://XXXXXXX.crm4.dynamics.com/main. But my real problem is that I dont know how to do that connection.

Comment: See if this helps you?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2015/04/21/dynamics-crm-developers-build-your-own-mobile-apps-for-windows-ios-and-android-part-3/ and 
https://github.com/DynamicsCRM/crm-mobilesdk-library-for-android

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using CRM 4? If it was more current version of CRM then you would most likely have an online version in which microsoft azure has plenty of tutorials where you can connect your CRM to azure then to your application. Xamarin is now owned by Microsoft and they have a sample application https://github.com/xamarin/app-crm

Comment: Its the CRM they gave us on work. Thank you for your response, I think im gonna give it a try. I'm so lost with this project, I think is somehow so big for me.

Comment: A suggestion would be to outsource. If you are on the east coast then I would recommend BroadPoint technologies

Comment: Not even from America, I´m from Spain. I think I´m gonna give up on this. Thank you all for your help. It´s to big and the effort isn´t worth, time passes too.